# customization for the search from the list in hybris backoffice

Tags: search, sap-commerce-cloud, relation, backoffice

I am trying to customize the search results for the search from list option for B2BUnit in usergroups. By default it searches using id and name. I want to add a new attribute through which I can see the results directly.

I tried to add the values in the advance search option but it does not change the way the results are displayed directly.

I want the results to be displayed without using advance search.
Image attached at the link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4juY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you probably need to define fields you'd like to use in Advance Search explicitly for your type (`B2BUnit`)

Like this:

```xml
<context type="Product" component="advanced-search">
    <as:advanced-search xmlns:as="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/advancedsearch" connection-operator="AND">
        <as:field-list disable-attributes-comparator="false" disable-subtypes-checkbox="false">
           <!-- ... your other attributes -->
           <as:field name="usergroups" operator="contains" selected="true"/>
        </as:field-list>
    </as:advanced-search>
</context>
```

See [this article](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/8b50ccf3866910149e1c9ebdd47f12be.html?q=backoffice%20advanced%20search#loio8b50ccf3866910149e1c9ebdd47f12be) for details.